# Can Cloudformation designer generate visualizations for resources launched without CFT

Tags: terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws

I have few resources in AWS which are launched using Terraform and some of them are manual create using AWS console. Some of the resources are launched using Cloudformation template.

I know Cloudformation designer gives you visualization of cloudformation templates. Terraform graph can provide dependent resources diagram too.

But can any service within AWS provide complete architecture and resources and dependencies for all resources launched either via CFT, Terraform or manual launch?

Comment: Might want to check out https://github.com/iann0036/former2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any service within AWS provide

There is **no such AWS service or tool**. There used to be [AWS CloudFormer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-aws-cloudformation-templates-using-cloudformer/) which could help a bit with this, but its not maintained any more.

Instead, as indicated in comments, you could use [former2](https://github.com/iann0036/former2) which is a **third party tool**. `former2` does not generate visualizations, but can reveres-engineer CFN templates from existing resources. Once having these templates you can try CFN designer to visualize them.